# Jquery Код не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть html файл с таким содержанием:

```
<fieldset>
 <label for="checkbox-6">
  Чекбокс 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="Значение первого чекбокса" id="checkbox-6">
 </label>
 <label for="checkbox-7">
  Чекбокс 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="Значение второго чекбокса" id="checkbox-7">
 </label>
 <label for="checkbox-8">
  В общем, чекбоксов очень много...
  <input type="checkbox" value="Значение третьего чекбокса" id="checkbox-8">
 </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  Fieldset второй
 <label for="checkbox-9">
  Чекбокс 1
  <input type="checkbox" value="Значение первого чекбокса" id="checkbox-9">
 </label>
 <label for="checkbox-10">
  Чекбокс 2
  <input type="checkbox" value="Значение второго чекбокса" id="checkbox-10">
 </label>
 <label for="checkbox-11">
  Чекбокс 3
  <input type="checkbox" value="Значение третьего чекбокса" id="checkbox-11">
 </label>
</fieldset>
```

Fieldset'ов также очень много

Подключаю jquery скрипт, который выводит текст отмеченных чекбоксов из **всех** fieldset'ов:

```
var fielsetText = "";
$('fieldset input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
   fielsetText = fielsetText + " " + $.trim($(this).parent().text());
});
alert(fielsetText);
```

Все работает! В алерте выводится текст отмеченных чекбоксов

Теперь мне нужно вывести текст отмеченных чекбоксов **только из первого** fieldset'a, делаю так:

```
var fielsetText = "";
var num = 1;
$('fieldset:nth-child(' + num + ') input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
   fielsetText = fielsetText + " " + $.trim($(this).parent().text());
});
alert(fielsetText);
```

Но... увы... в алерте пусто...
Подскажите, в чем ошибка?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Неправда, не пусто, с таким html-кодом `nth-child(1)` отлично работает. Видимо, вы привели неполный html-код и на самом деле первый fieldset не является самым первым потомком своего родительского элемента